# The benefits of hosting a bot on Azure Bot Service compare to hosting a bot on a typical Web App hosting

Tags: botframework

A bot is essentially a web API and so it can be hosted on any web service.

I am abit confused when one of the following approaches should be prefered over each other:

- Option #1 Host a Bot on Azure Bot Service
- Option #2 Host a bot as a plain PaaS Web API

Currently I am hosting my bot on a plain Azure PaaS App Services. It is working very well.

However, I expect there must be some advantages to hosting a bot on Azure Bot Service.

When I go through the documentations the following example shows how to Create an Azure Bot Service in Azure Portal, download its code, change it then deploy it again to the same Azure Bot Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-download-source-code?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

In contrast, the following example shows how to build a bot in Visual Studio and publish it to an Azure Web App:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-deploy-azure?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

What are the advantages of hosting a bot on Azure Bot Service?

Is there any resource or article that contrasts the two options?

Comment: If you jsut down-vote without any comments, I won't be able to improve the question. This is a real life matter and I am hpoing that I can get the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

They are essentially the same thing under the hood.  A bot is basically just an API endpoint so there are many ways to host you bot.  If you create A bot service you get options to add other services from the creation page. Whereas if you just create a web app or app service you will have to manually add these things.

Creating a Web App Bot will allow you to all in one step create:

- Bot Channels Registration
- Choose a template to start with
- Configure a Luis app
- Add Azure Storage
- Add application insights